# getElementById returning null but getElementsByClassName works, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am really wondering why getElementById is returing null, where as same element I am able to access using get elements by className. It will be great if somebody helps me to understand what is causing this.
Please find below code, its a functional react component where i am passing handleClose function  as props, which closes the modal, it just not needed so i have put only Modal component code.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

const A11yModal = ({ handleClose }) => {
  const focusClose = useRef(null)

  var closeBtn_cls = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-close")
   var closeIcon=document.getElementById('btnclose')

  useEffect(() => {
    focusClose.current.focus();
    console.log("using Id",closeIcon);
    console.log("using ClassName",closeBtn_cls);
    }, [])

  function onKeyPressed(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      handleClose()
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="modal display-block">
      <section className="modal-main" role="dialog"
        aria-modal="true" onKeyDown={(e) => onKeyPressed(e)}>
        <button className="btn-close" id="btnclose" onClick={(e) => handleClose(e)} ref={focusClose}>
          X
        </button>
        <h1 id="modal_title" className="title" >Modal</h1>
        <div id="full_description" className="description" aria-describedby="full_description">
          <p>Description goes here.</p>
        </div>        
        <button className="close_btn" id="closebtn" onClick={(e) => handleClose(e)}> Close </button>     
      </section>
    </div>
  )
}

export default A11yModal
```

Comment: When these methods run, there is is no JSX that the func has emitted. There should be no need to use these methods at all. React should abstract away the need to do direct DOM manipulation in almost every case. Consider using a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: Seems like OP is already using a ref like `ref={focusClose}`

Comment: Also, this way is not appropriate way to show Modal, if you render it deep in DOM hierarchy, as you will find your self fighting against `z-Index` and "stack context" which make your Modal render behind some other elements. Consider using `createPortal` which is designed for that purpose, ... or use a library for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var closeBtn_cls = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-close")
```

At the moment this line of code finishes running, `closeBtn_cls` will have nothing in it (assuming this is the first render and there is nothing else with that class name on the page). But `closeBtn_cls` is a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). This array-like object has the peculiar property that it will be dynamically changed as elements are added to the DOM. So by the time the `useEffect` runs, the element has been added to the page and the collection updated.

getElementById does not return an HTMLCollection, so it does not update on the fly.

---

While that addresses the difference, you should also know that this is not the recommended way to do things in react. In react you should use refs to get a reference to the dom element. You seem to be aware of that, as you're used refs in your example, so i recommend just deleting the code that uses getElementsByClassName and getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the reason that you see elements while using className is that on console the elements are evaluated when you expand objects which in this case is an `HTMLCollection`, so even though at the initial render there is no element present, after the execution of useEffect you will display the data into the console and by that the HTMLCollection is being initialized and the reference to the array is causes the values to be seen whereas while using the id you are directly returning a single element and there is no element present at the time of initial render.

```js
const { useRef, useEffect } = React;

const A11yModal = ({ handleClose }) => {
  const focusClose = useRef(null)

  var closeBtn_cls = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-close")
   var closeIcon=document.getElementById('btnclose')
 console.log('class value', closeBtn_cls[0]);
  useEffect(() => {
    focusClose.current.focus();
    console.log("using Id",closeIcon);
    console.log("using ClassName",closeBtn_cls);
    }, [])

  function onKeyPressed(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      handleClose()
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="modal display-block">
      <section className="modal-main" role="dialog"
        aria-modal="true" onKeyDown={(e) => onKeyPressed(e)}>
        <button className="btn-close" id="btnclose" onClick={(e) => handleClose(e)} ref={focusClose}>
          X
        </button>
        <h1 id="modal_title" className="title" >Modal</h1>
        <div id="full_description" className="description" aria-describedby="full_description">
          <p>Description goes here.</p>
        </div>        
        <button className="close_btn" id="closebtn" onClick={(e) => handleClose(e)}> Close </button>     
      </section>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<A11yModal />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```